# state is not mapping on props in Redux Saga

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-saga

I am practicing redux saga. I've seen all similar question but they didn't help me .

Actually my actions are dispatching, fetching data from url and state is changing but no mapping to props.

My Code

**Home.js**

```
class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Welcome to Dog Saga</Text>
        <Button title={"Show Dog"} onPress={this.props.onRequestDog} />
        {this.props.loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={"red"} />
        ) : this.props.error ? (
          <Text>Error Occured</Text>
        ) : (
          <Image
            source={{ uri: this.props.url }}
            style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    url: state.url,
    loading: state.loading,
    error: state.error
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onRequestDog: () => dispatch(requestDog())
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);
```

**apiReducer.js**

```
import {
  API_CALL_REQUEST,
  API_CALL_SUCCESS,
  API_CALL_FAILURE
} from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  url: "",
  loading: false,
  error: false
};

const apiReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case API_CALL_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        url: "",
        loading: true,
        error: false
      };
    case API_CALL_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        url: action.url,
        loading: false,
        error: false
      };
    case API_CALL_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        url: "",
        loading: false,
        error: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default apiReducer;
```

**apiSaga.js**

```
import { takeEvery, call, put, all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import axios from "axios";
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";
import {
  requestDog,
  requestDogSuccess,
  requestDogError
} from "../actions/actions";

//watcher saga, watches for actions dispatached to the store , starts worker saga
export default function* watcherSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(types.API_CALL_REQUEST, workerSaga);
  //yield takeLatest(API_CALL_REQUEST, workerSaga);
}

// function that makes the api request and returns a Promise for response
function fetchDog() {
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"
  });
}

// worker saga: makes the api call when watcher saga sees the action
export  function* workerSaga() {

  try {
    
    //yield put(requestDog());
    const response = yield call(fetchDog);

    // dispatch a success action to the store with the new dog
    yield put(requestDogSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    // dispatch a failure action to the store with the error
    yield put(requestDogError());
  }
}
```

**Problem**

RequestDog is dispatching well and image url is also retrieving well but the changed state in store doesn't showing any effect component. Means image is not loading.

Picture will tell you the story what's happening.

[image: redux logger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you missed `apiReducer` state's key in your mapping:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    url: state.apiReducer.url,
    loading: state.apiReducer.loading,
    error: state.apiReducer.error
  };
};
```

or simply:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => state.apiReducer;
```

Comment: is it important to mention your reducer name while getting state ?

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq, true, as otherwise mapping is incorrect

Comment: if we have more than one reducer  ?

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq yeah, np, just change the key in the mapping accordingly. Or you see other issue with that?

Comment: ok got it. i'm stucked on this from 4 days. thanks for your help